# how to compare sql results

Tags: sql

How to get the minimum from a query result ?
[image of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRXPu.jpg)
i want the min of the [serving-num], is it possible ?

Comment: You can use a SQL Request or other thing to get you result.

Comment: Investigating the MIN function would be a place for *you* to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the relevant information as text in the question itself, not as links to images. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i tried this:   select min([serving-num])
from(
select count([Server-ID])[serving-num],[Server-ID]
from [In-Order]
where [Server-ID] in(
select Id
from Employees
where Fname='dima' or Fname= 'sami')
group by [Server-ID])

Comment: red line error is shown under first [serving-num] as " invalid column name 'serving-num' ".

Answer (score 0):

```
select min([serving-num] 
from(
select count([Server-ID])[serving-num],[Server-ID]
from [In-Order]
where [Server-ID] in(
select Id
from Employees
where Fname='dima' or Fname= 'sami')
group by [Server-ID]
)t
```

the problem was all about the letter t i inserted in the last line.